# How do I turn Moose objects into JSON for use in Catalyst?

Tags: perl, json, serialization, moose, catalyst

I have a series of Moose objects that I'm looking to feed to [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-2.29/XS.pm) by way of [Catalyst::View::JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Catalyst-View-JSON-0.30/lib/Catalyst/View/JSON.pm). JSON::XS is unable to encode blessed data-structures. I know that there is [MooseX::Storage::Format::JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/MooseX-Storage-0.27/lib/MooseX/Storage/Format/JSON.pm) which can -- kinda -- do what I want; but, it seems pretty overly heavy. What I'm looking for is essentially the same information that [XXX.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/XXX-0.16/lib/XXX.pm) provides. I just want the raw-data structures recursively unblessed so `JSON::XS` (the driver for `JSON::Any` that `C:V:JSON` uses internally) can display it.

What is the best way go about using `Catalyst::View::JSON` and `JSON::XS` with `Moose` objects? It seems I have four obvious choices:

1. Make `Catalyst::View::JSON` work with Moose Objects, by patching `C:V:JSON` to read from `freeze` and finalize the request if the argument exposed is a Moose Object.
2. Patch `JSON::XS` to fallback to return value of `$obj->freeze if $obj->isa('Moose') && $obj->does('MooseX::Storage::Format::JSON')`. I should look into `MX:S:F:JSON` to make sure that the class used by `JSON::Any`, and by proxy `MX:S:F:JSON`, is `JSON::XS` (hate to think of the bugs galore if `JSON::Any` choses a different internal encoder for the Moose object that `JSON::XS` is called to use.
3. Figure out how to recursively-unbless and let `Catalyst::View::JSON` do its thing.
4. Don't use `Catalyst::View::JSON` at all. Just write to STDOUT `$obj->freeze` and manually finalize requests.. This seems the most hackish.

I'm sure there are some other options, any ideas? What is my best bet?

Comment: I file a [bug report on rt for `C:V:JSON`](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=60564&results=af4f9b8bf7a79ca52896b9b59dbf480a) just for the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it or hate it my ultimate solution was to revert back to the now deprecated [JSON::Syck](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/YAML-Syck-1.11/lib/JSON/Syck.pm) which does exactly what I want. Here is a quick non-Moose example of logical non-Moose serialization to JSON.

```
use JSON::Syck;
use URI;
use feature ':5.10';
say JSON::Syck::Dump(
 bless { foo => URI->new("http://www.evancarroll.com") }
)
```

I wrote the author about [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/YAML-LibYAML-0.33/lib/YAML/XS.pm) he was not game for adding the functionality. Here is some of the text  (taken out of context from numerous messages to show why this feature isn't there) from [Marc Lehmann](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/) the JSON::XS maintainer:

> No, because you are using *JSON* and
>   not *Perl*. Perl is obviously capable
>   of representing any Perl data
>   structure, but JSON is not, so you
>   need to tell it what to do. Many
>   people naively request something like
>   "just dump the data structure", but
>   JSON can't even represent all perl
>   data structures that are non-objects.
>
> ...
>
> Your question is like: why can't I
>   send this 1MB jpeg image as ascii file
>   - simply because ascii cannot represent octets.
>
> ...
>
> Or maybe you justw ant to to throw
>   some garbage at it and expect JSON::XS
>   to do what is good for you (but wrong
>   for other people) - there is simply no
>   way for JSON::XS to magically guess
>   what *you* want.
>
> ...
>
> TO_JSON is it. Anything else is just
>   wild guessing.
>
> ...
>
> Then maybe you should try stuff that
>   JSON can actually represent. Throwing
>   some object hierarchy at it and hoping
>   it would do "the right thing" is
>   clearly bad software engineering - try
>   not to resort hacks, when your protocl
>   requires JSON, then send JSON, don't
>   expect the json library to fix up your
>   invalid message in the first place.

I don't know how to respond to that, other than **I DON'T CARE. JUST WORK! LIKE ::SYCK**. I don't expect objects to transform to JSON perfectly. But, I think I fall in the 80% that just want it to work. I'm using JSON for jQuery import not performing banking transactions during brain surgery. Ultimately, I don't want to use a special role... I want anything sent to it to magically be transformed for me to a level that makes it useful in a response to a jQuery JSON request.

## UPDATE

Sorry, I missed these replies until someone said I was trolling in an unrelated medium. MooseX::Storage doesn't work for non-Moose classes, I want a general way to represent the stash in a JSON format. Unfortunately, some of those members of the stash are Moose objects. XML::Simple can do this, `Data::Dumper` can do this, JSON::Syck can do this, the list goes on -- I just want it done. It doesn't have to be 1:1 with Perl, and to be honest I want it done fairly close to the way `JSON::Syck` does it by default. My argument here then, is, "How do I get `JSON::XS` to work exactly like `JSON::Syck` does currently"? And, your answer is you can't. So I've not employed a different solution. Writing code costs money, why would I want to write `to_JSON` if Syck is already doing it right... I'd like to say the burden is on the nay-sayers to show what Syck is serializing a fashion that isn't desirable.  Also, do keep in mind `JSON::Syck` was seeded by [Audry](http://search.cpan.org/~audreyt/), who is by no means a troll, idiot, or "brain damaged"; or, any of the other terms that are being thrown my way. I will close with this: the lack of a bad serialization route of `JSON::Syck` and the desired output already *just-working* leads me to believe this is a good choice for me. And, what could MooseX::*:JSON be doing differently with an arbitrary Moose object? Why do you think that code can't be written to accept a Moose object rather than a method on it? If you think otherwise, answer with something of substance -- I'd like to see a better response. Thanks. (directed toward @jrockway, and @Ether)

Comment: Lehmann is exactly right.  And now I know why he hates users so much.

Do you *really* not understand where he's coming from?  Some things in Perl can't be represented as JSON.  Instead of guessing, JSON::XS requires you to do the conversion.  MooseX::Storage is a module that converts Moose classes to something that can be represented as JSON.

Comment: "I don't know how to respond to that, other than I DON'T CARE. JUST WORK!"

Aren't you the programmer?  It's your job to make it "just work".  Having "infrastructure modules" do a random guessing that works some of the time, probably maybe, sounds like something they'd do down the hall with the Perl inspired gemstone language.  Sounds frustrating to me!

Comment: "I want anything sent to it to magically be transformed for me to a level that makes it useful in a response to a jQuery JSON request."

Did you look at MooseX::Storage at all?

Comment: Great I couldn't get MooseX::Storage to work at all for my nested Moose objects. But JSON::Syck worked first try!

Comment: I don't suppose there's any way to exclude a Moose attribute with Syck though.

Answer (score 5):

I tend to do option 3 using MooseX::Storage to provide a `pack()` method that returns a Perl data structure that I can stuff in my stash so the View can render it as it chooses.

Also note that JSON::Any can be forced (by the environment, or by passing the proper parameters to `import()`) to pick a specific backend. This is how the test suite works, and it is documented.

Comment: @jrockway You could use the deserialization routines from KiokuDB, or write your own ... but since MooseX::Storage at this point is three or four years old and well tested in *many* production environments those aren't great solutions.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about unblessing your object completely and making it completely unusable (from a Moose perspective), try unbless from `Data::Structure::Util`.

I personally prefer `MooseX::Storage` for a much more elegant and sustainable solution.

Comment: Moose has only ever guaranteed this will work in the default case. MooseX::GlobRef or MooseX::NonMoose will make this solution less than optimal for some cases.

Comment: @perigrin!! upvoted, I've needed the functionality of MooseX::GlobRef before, I can use that today in place of some ad-hoc code to record the File::Stat before the file was opened

Comment: @rodigo, while a good idea this doesn't work. `unbless( URI->new('http://foobar.com') )`, returns a scalar reference `\"http://www.foobar.com"` which `JSON::XS` can't parse `cannot encode reference to scalar 'http://www.foobar.com' unless the scalar is 0 or 1 at -e line 1.`